# c# BitConverter.GetBytes operations in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How can i C# BitConverter.GetBytes() operation in standart C++.

for example;

```
int k=4;
byte[] byteK = BitConverter.GetBytes(K);
```

> - - byte[0] = 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
>   - byte[1] = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   - byte[2] = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   - byte[3] = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Have you done some trials? Can you post your current code?

Comment: 1) detect the endianness of the architecture you are running on

2) allocate a new byte array of the proper size based on your method overload

3) use & operator to mask off bits into proper buckets

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an integer type variable occupies 4 bytes,

```
int k = 4;
unsigned char byteK[4];

byteK[0] = (unsigned char)k & 0xFF;
byteK[1] = (unsigned char)((k >> 8) & 0xFF);
byteK[2] = (unsigned char)((k >> 16) & 0xFF);
byteK[3] = (unsigned char)((k >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

The same can be performed using a loop to generalize the operation to data types of different sizes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfBytes; i++)
{
    byteK[i] = (unsigned char)(( k >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF);
}
```

The order will depend on the endianness of the system, which can be determined using a simple bitwise test.
    int x = 1;
    char *ptr = (char*)&x;
    if (*ptr == 1)
    {   //Little Endian
    }